# Constructor is not called with /NODEFAULTLIB

Tags: c++, constructor, llvm

I'm using /NODEFAULTLIB to disable CRT(C Runtime), however my constructor is not called, which ends up causing an error in std::map (Access violation) because it is not initialized properly, since std::map constructor it's not called.

Code compiled with LLVM 8.0.0, compiled in mode debug x86

```
class c_test
{
public:

    c_test( int a ) // Constructor not called
    {
        printf( "Test: %i\n", a ); // Doesn't appear and breakpoint is not reached
    }

    void add( const std::string& key, const std::string& val )
    {
        _data[ key ] = val;
    }

private:
    std::map< std::string, std::string >                        _data;
};

c_test test{ 1337 };

int main()
{
    test.add( "qwrqrqr", "23142421" );
    test.add( "awrqw", "12asa1faf" );

    return 1;
}
```

I've implemented my own functions new(HeapAlloc), delete(HeapFree), printf, memcpy, memmove, etc, and all are working perfectly, I have no idea why this happening.

Comment: You can not use most of the library stuff with `/NODEFAULTLIB` as well as rely on dynamic initialization stage.

Comment: I can't use some functions with /NODEFAULTLIB, I am absolutely sure that the constructor is not being called because my breakpoint is not called, printf is not the problem

Comment: The STL may rely on the CRT. Why do you want to disable it anyway? There is *nothing* you can actually gain by disabling it and you *will* create lots of hard to detect issues.

Comment: because I need an executable with the smallest possible size and I also need to avoid calling some winapis that the CRT calls(e.g: LoadLibraryW) 
to hinder reverse engineering in my executable

Comment: While C++ does not even try to follow "not pay for what you don't use" concept I doubt that you can save a lot of bytes by avoiding linking CRT. And even if you save some it may turn out that code size of your executable is insignificant compared to resources so all that runtime avoidance can turn out to be a waste of time. Part about "hinder reverse engineering" makes no sense...

Comment: Well, current file size with crt: 142KB, without crt: 17KB.

I am writing an anticheat, I want to avoid calling winapis because I would need to inject a dll without crt(this dll would be hidden in memory to avoid being manipulated and easily accessed to avoid reverse engineering or 
or easily dumped my memory), CRT calls winapis that can be easily intercepted through hooks by attackers and accessing the callstack could easily find my anticheat module that should be hidden in memory

Comment: "Hidden memory" in Windows has no meaning. You can go to DOS and manipulate int 0x12 and int 0x15 to return false information though.

Comment: What would be more work than solving CRT problem, I believe it is just some
initialization that is missing

Comment: If you reimplement all the missing stuff rom CRT then most likely size of your executable will grow significantly, most likely even exceeding size of executable with normal CRT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem and solved, one guy from another forum said that I needed manually call constructors that are stored in pointers in .CRT section, I just did it and it worked perfectly

[image]

[image]

[image]

I just called _GLOBAL__sub_I_main_cpp function that calls my constructor and solved all my problems, thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the CRT is madness.

This performs crucial functions, such as static initialisation. Lack of static initialisation is why your map is in a crippled state. I would also wholly expect various parts of the standard library to just stop working; you're really creating a massive problem for yourself.

Don't reinvent little pieces of critical machinery — turn the CRT back on and use the code the experts wrote. There is really nothing of relative value to gain by turning it off.

Comment: Many functions work perfectly without CRT(obviously I need to recreate some functions that are used by stl, like new, delete, etc), I know some people who use std::map/std::unordered_map without CRT and without any problem, I can use std:: vector/std::deque/std::list without any problem in my project.

In my case it will be worth disabling CRT, Do you have any ideas on how to solve my problem?

Comment: @cYeR I doubt that any of those containers may work without CRT as all of them (among other things) rely on working exception handling.

Comment: This is my advice. You are of course welcome to ignore it, but just asserting "no it's worth it" won't change my answer that it isn't :)

Comment: @VTT You can use these containers without CRT, just create the functions that these containers need and disable exceptions, I can guarantee that it works perfectly

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit I agree perfectly with what you said, but there are special cases(like mine) that really need to disable CRT

Comment: I think you need to re-evaluate whether you really have a special case, or just think you do.

Comment: @cYeR You may need to disable it, but you also need to keep it enabled, because you are using code that requires it. That other people have used some of the code is irrelevant to your problem.